# Configure CiviMember / CiviContribute for livery company quarterage fees

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, renewals

Can anyone advise me on the best way to manage CiviCRM payments for a City of London livery company? I have tried various permutations using CiviMember and CiviContribute, but I haven't cracked it yet.

This is the basic scenario:

- Livery company members are effectively members for life.
- They don't renew their membership annually as such, but they pay annual 'quarterage' fees.
- There are other payments, such as one-off 'fines' when they become Freemen or Liverymen.
- Even if they are late to pay their quarterage, they remain fully functional members.
- There are 3 or 4 quarterage price points, including gratis. The actual rate varies from year to year.
- Invoices for the coming year (from July 1) need to be bulk emailed to all members in June, customised to show the correct amount owed.
- Payments may be full or partial and they are recorded manually by the administrator.
- There is also a rollover date in the middle of the year.
- The administrator needs to get quarterage reports showing individual records with amounts paid and amounts outstanding.  Potentially a member could still owe one amount for the period just ended and another for the new period.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this setup:

1. Auto-renewed annual memberships (different membership types for each amount).
2. Fixed renewal dates (July 1).
3. Adjust the Membership Status rules to allow "Grace" status to extend several years (or whenever it is that you're ready to say good by to non-engaging members).

Memberships are often tricky because of language - if some of the default language needs to be altered, you can do that with the string replacement features.

1 + 3 will effectively mean your members don't really expire, since "Grace" status is considered 'current' (normally), but you'll have the renewal mechanisms for reporting and payments and notifications.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll get onto it. Mike